# CSS Hyperlink Button not working in android Firefox?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a CSS Button, generated on 
http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/button-generator/

The code seems to work on desktop chrome and firefox
And on mobile (android) chrome, but not on Android Firefox.
It simply does nothing.

Here is my example page (open with firefox on your android):

https://dokumente-online.com/test200.html

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.testbutton {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
width:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}.testbutton:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.testbutton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <br>
   <a class="testbutton" style="margin:20px;padding:10px;width:200px" href="http://orf.at">Button</a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

happened to me too. Remove position:relative; Firefox mobile does not support that for some reason.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .testbutton {
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
        background-color:#ededed;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
        border-top-left-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
        border-top-right-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
        border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#777777;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
        line-height:50px;
    width:100px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    }.testbutton:hover {
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
        background-color:#dfdfdf;
    }.testbutton:active {
        top:1px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <br>
       <a class="testbutton" style="margin:20px;padding:10px;width:200px" href="http://orf.at">Button</a>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems they guy behinde hyperlinkcode.com does not want to be reached (Ed Zivkovic), he has neither email or contact... so nobody can tell him to remove that position:relative bug. (Why does it need position:relative anyway?)

I remember running over that problem (that I can not click buttons) on a big companies website, where I could not checkout on their payment page using firefox. I began to dislike firefox and stopped using it...  But I guess simply no one ist testing android firefox a lot :-(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the testbutton.active{} seems to be disliked by firefox, removing the position:relative; will make the button work again.

It seems the css button generator is not up to date...